# order by based on string alias value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this below. What i want is make the alias of DESCRIPTION which value is 'Qty' as the first.

```
SELECT   'Net Others' AS DESCRIPTION,
          AREA_ID FROM SALES
UNION ALL
SELECT   'Qty' AS DESCRIPTION,
          AREA_ID FROM SALES
UNION ALL
SELECT   'Sales Others' AS DESCRIPTION,
          AREA_ID FROM SALES
UNION ALL
SELECT   'Discount Others' AS DESCRIPTION,
          AREA_ID FROM SALES
```

I try already adding

```
order by case when DESCRIPTION= 'QTY' then 1 end
```

it comes error

> ORDER BY item must be the number of a SELECT-list expression

I try already make like this also not work

```
order by (DESCRIPTION|| 'Qty') ASC
```

So how to make order by on this case ?
I search on google but i didn't got like my case. As info i use Oracle database.

Comment: Where is `Type` defined? Also please post some example data, not just the query.

Comment: What happens if you wrap the entire `UNION` query in an outer-query which performs the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @Dai it's just a string. I named it as alias. Then this alias i will call in my report

Comment: @Dai I'm sorry i made wrong in my query before. it must be DESCRIPTION not TYPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
select DESCRIPTION ,AREA_ID 
from 
   (
    SELECT   'Net Others' AS DESCRIPTION,
              AREA_ID FROM SALES
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Qty' AS DESCRIPTION,
              AREA_ID FROM SALES
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Sales Others' AS DESCRIPTION,
              AREA_ID FROM SALES
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Discount Others' AS DESCRIPTION,
              AREA_ID FROM SALES
    )         
 ORDER BY DECODE(DESCRIPTION,'Qty',1);
```

Demo:

```
select DESCRIPTION ,AREA_ID 
from 
   (
    SELECT   'Net Others' AS DESCRIPTION, 'AREA_ID' AREA_ID
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Qty' AS DESCRIPTION, 'AREA_ID'  AREA_ID
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Sales Others' AS DESCRIPTION,  'AREA_ID' AREA_ID
    FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   'Discount Others' AS DESCRIPTION, 'AREA_ID' AREA_ID
    FROM DUAL
    )         
 ORDER BY DECODE(DESCRIPTION,'Qty',1)
```

Output:

```
DESCRIPTION     AREA_ID
--------------- -------
Qty             AREA_ID
Discount Others AREA_ID
Sales Others    AREA_ID
Net Others      AREA_ID
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. It's not error but still not work the order itself

Comment: I guess the aboe query will give your QTY as the first in order. Do you need anything else.

Comment: Yes I just need QTY as the first order.

Comment: Then my query will give you QTY at first in order. See demo. or you just need QTY row ?

Comment: ohh yes you are right. I'm sorry. I directly change my package procedure then run my report. It still not like your demo. So the problem is coming from the report now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you took after AS two names, looks like first is names.

try something like this

```
SELECT 'Net Others' AS AREA_ID FROM SALES
etc...
```

hope it helps